# Issues with connecting to ubuntu instance in amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having some issues with connecting to ubuntu instance in amazon. I can connect to the default instance with default AMI installation. But when I select ubuntu, I cannot ssh into it.

It says operation timeout. I have tried instantiating other instances rebooting changing key pairs etc.

```
 ssh -i mykey.pem ubuntu@ec2-54-203-164-37.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
ssh: connect to host ec2-54-203-164-37.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

The strange thing when I stop the instance, then only the ssh command connects and says the are you sure you want to verify the fingerprint thing.

I can easily log into the micro instance with the default AMI installation

I have added the ssh port in the security group as well

Comment: did you make sure the ssh port is visible from the ip you're using? (or open to the public?)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting via Putty ,just use a ppk file and please check once 
also you can add ICMP to your Security Group and check for ping resposnses

Regards
Devashish

Comment: Ping works when I add ICMP to the rules. It's just ssh that doesn't work